# If we are typing wrong field in the username & pass. It shows a login failure alert, but its calling the next Activity. Tow to fix this?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

This code is for my login Activity.

I have used an Intent to call the next page in the `onPostExecute()` method, but it could not work properly.
If we are typing a wrong value in the username & pass, it shows the login failure alert but it calls the next Activity.

How to fix this?

```
public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    Context context;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;    

    BackgroundWorker(Context ctx) {
        context = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String type = params[0];    
        String login_url = "http://techblog.96.lt/login.php";

        if (type.equals("Login")) {

            try {
                String username = params[1];
                String pass = params[2];
                URL url = new URL(login_url);

                HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpUrlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpUrlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpUrlConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpUrlConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8") + "&" + URLEncoder.encode("pass", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(pass, "UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpUrlConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
                String result = "";
                String line = "";
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                    result += line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpUrlConnection.disconnect();
                return result;    

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }    
        }
         return null;    
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Login Success");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            Intent i = new Intent(context, NewActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(i);

            alertDialog.setMessage(result);
            alertDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate (Void...values)
{
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`onPostExecute` will always start the next Activity regardless of the value of the `String result`.

You need to check that value for whatever determines if you've successfully logged in. Also check it for null since that is also being returned by `doInBackground`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `onPostExecute` method. You need to check response code inside your `doInBackground` method and depending on the result you need to return an appropriate `String`. Then inside `onPostExecute` check that response from `doInBackground` and take appropriate actions.